# my express app does 3 requests then gives error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a route that renders an ejs page and request data from the database and I have an object containing the data I want to show.
it shows the data but then do 2 more requests which make 1 error twice

```
  app.get("/vote/:id", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {  
    let botVote = await botDoc.findOne({ id: req.params.id });
    renderWeb("vote.ejs", req, res, { bot: botVote });
  });
```

```
<html lang="en">
    <%- include('partials/head') %>  
<body>
    
    <%- include('partials/navbar') %> <br>
    
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 69px; margin-left: 40%;">

    <div class="vote">
        <%= bot.id %> 
    </div>
        
    </div>
        
    </div>
<br><%- include('partials/footer') %> 


<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**
TypeError: D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\views\vote.ejs:10
8|
9|

> > 10|         <%= bot.id %>
> > 11|     
> > 12|
> > 13|

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
at eval ("D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\views\vote.ejs":18:30)
at vote (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
at tryHandleCache (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at renderWeb (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\main.js:32:9)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
TypeError: D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\views\vote.ejs:10
8|
9|

> > 10|         <%= bot.id %>
> > 11|     
> > 12|
> > 13|     
> > Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
> > at eval ("D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\views\vote.ejs":18:30)
> > at vote (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
> > at tryHandleCache (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
> > at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
> > at View.render (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
> > at tryRender (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
> > at Function.render (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
> > at ServerResponse.render (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
> > at renderWeb (D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2\main.js:32:9)
> > at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> > PS D:\Users\ahmed\Documents\Coding\Projects\Beats'List2> node .
> > **

Comment: whats the url you're calling? Please don't forget you have to set `id` in your url, for example `/vote/12345`

Comment: I am calling /vote/123213 and it displays the id but it gives the errors above.
and in the network tab it shows that 2 ```icon.png``` are requested and gives 500 server error @João Pimentel Ferreira

Comment: Which function is `botDoc.findOneq`? Add an extra line `console.log(botVote)` to see if this value is what you expect